# How does the correlation name work in the inner query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query to "Find all courses taught in both the Fall 2009 semester and in the Spring 2010 semester" as

```
SELECT
    course_id
FROM
    section S
WHERE
    semester = 'Fall'
AND YEAR = 2009
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        section T
    WHERE
        semester = 'Spring'
    AND YEAR = 2010
    AND S.course_id = T.course_id
);
```

In the second part of the where clause of the inner query you could see `S.course_id=T.course_id`. What is `S.course_id`? Is that the `course_id` of the relation produced by the outer query ?

Comment: Yes.`S.course_id` is supplied by the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Yes S.course_id is the column in the outer query.
S.course_id=T.course_id selects only the record with the course id in both the inner and outer queries equals

---

Inorder to find all courses taught in both the Fall 2009 semester and in the Spring 2010 semester your query should be like

```
SELECT course_id FROM  section 
WHERE 
semester = 'Fall' AND year = '2009'
UNION 
SELECT course_id FROM  section
WHERE 
semester = 'Spring' AND year = '2010'
;
```

**Refer** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/449be